# What are the required permissions for the Azure Backup Service?

Tags: azure, backup

I am met with the following error details when investigating why an Azure encrypted VM backup failed, but the link provided with the error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-encryption) doesn't resolve my question: **exactly which permissions should I grant?** All it says is that "The required permissions are prefilled for Key permissions and Secret permissions." Well, that's not a lot of help! I had those permissions already set as default I thought, because I do have lots of backups/snapshots; obviously backups have been working in the past. If I am missing some permission now, is it a Key permission, or a Secret permission? It's not clear! I do see I have the following set up right now:

**Key permissions:**

*Key Management Operations*

- **Get** (checked)
- **List** (checked)
- Update
- Create
- Import
- Delete
- Recover
- **Backup** (checked)
- Restore

*Cryptographic Operations:*

- Decrypt
- Encrypt
- Unwrap Key
- Wrap Key
- Verify
- Sign

*Privileged Key Operations*

- Purge

**Secret permissions:**

*Secret Management Operations*

- **Get** (checked)
- **List** (checked)
- Set
- Delete
- Recover
- Backup
- Restore

*Privileged Secret Operations*

- Purge

**Certificate permissions:**

*Certificate Management Operations*

- Get
- List
- Update
- Create
- Import
- Delete
- Recover
- Backup
- Restore
- Manage Contacts
- Manage Certificate Authorities
- Get Certificate Authorities
- List Certificate Authorities
- Set Certificate Authorities
- Delete Certificate Authorities

*Privileged Certificate Operations*

- Purge

Below is the error I see for my backup:

**Error Code**

UserErrorKeyVaultPermissionsNotConfigured

**Error Message**

Azure Backup Service does not have sufficient permissions to Key Vault for Backup of Encrypted Virtual Machines.

**Recommended Action**

Please grant the required permissions to the Azure Backup Service. Refer https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-encryption/

**Related Links**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-encryption

Comment: Tonight, the next backup ought to occur automatically so we'll see!

Comment: Could it solve the issue now?

Comment: Alert
 
Backup failure
Status
 
Active
Alert type
 
Backup
Severity
 
Critical
Backup item
 
fileserver
Backup item type
 
Azure virtual machine
Creation time
 
7/5/2019, 4:13:29 AM
Latest occurrence time
 
7/5/2019, 4:13:29 AM
Occurrence count
 
1
Description
 
Azure Backup Service does not have sufficient permissions to Key Vault for Backup of Encrypted Virtual Machines.
Recommended action
 
Please grant the required permissions to the Azure Backup Service. Refer https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-encryption/

Comment: I found a statement at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-encryption that says, "If your VM is encrypted using BEK only, remove the selection for Key permissions since you only need permissions for secrets." It seems I have BEK--at least that's what my Secret Types are. I'll try this next.

Comment: Well, you could have a try. But if the permissions are more than that, it should work, it’s wired.

Comment: Any update now?

Comment: I think I missed the last step in the sequence below and my test didn't actually execute as a result. Will try again tonight! I realize step 6 be overkill.
Steps: 
1. Search for "Key vaults".
2. Click on my key vault.
3. Click "Access policies".
4. Click "Backup Management Service".
5. Click on the Key permissions dropdown and uncheck all checkboxes.
6. Click on the Secret permissions dropdown and choose the Get, List, Backup, and Restore checkboxes.
7. Click OK.
8. Click Save back on the "Access policies" screen.

Comment: The backups began to work again as of July 11th! Performing the steps I wrote above fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to correct this via http://portal.azure.com (I realize step 6 might be overkill as the Restore permission might be unnecessary here--but hey, this worked):

1. Search for "Key vaults".
2. Click on my key vault.
3. Click "Access policies".
4. Click "Backup Management Service".
5. Click on the Key permissions dropdown and uncheck all checkboxes.
6. Click on the Secret permissions dropdown and choose the Get, List, Backup, and Restore checkboxes.
7. Click OK.
8. Click Save back on the "Access policies" screen.

The last step above is important as missing it will cause your changes NOT to be saved. I wrote these steps up and followed them as influenced by a statement I found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-encryption that says, "If your VM is encrypted using BEK only, remove the selection for Key permissions since you only need permissions for secrets." It seems I have BEK--at least that's what my Secret Types are. And indeed, the above worked. The backups began to work again as of July 11th!

Answer (score 1):

It looks you missed the `Backup` permission of the `Secret permissions`.

In step 6 of the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-encryption#provide-permissions),

[image]

I suppose you give the permissions manually instead of selecting `Azure Backup` of the `Configure from template (optional)`, if you select it, the permissions will be chosen automatically, that is the `The required permissions are prefilled for Key permissions and Secret permissions` means.

[image]

Comment: I felt like marking your input as the answer because it led me in the right direction, but I suppose my configuration was somewhat different so I wrote exactly what I did separately in another answer post, separate from yours. Notably, I removed all selections for Key permissions since you only need permissions for Secrets, per the Microsoft post I linked to in my answer text. Your answer above had 3 Key permissions still set, but it didn't work for me like that.

Comment: @ShieldOfSalvation Well, also glad that you solved the issue.